# Copying a list of files to a new folder

Tags: csv, applescript

I have a list of image filenames (csv file) and I want to check if these images exist in a folder of images. If the image exists I want to copy it over to new folder.

I built a sample code that runs through without error and duplicated the first matching file to the destination folder correctly. However the rest of the files it returns that it doesn't find a match although they are clearly present in the source folder. Any ideas what is going wrong?

```
--Step 1.  Get file path and read file.
set csvFile to (choose file with prompt "Select CSV file...") as text
set csvRecords to read file csvFile using delimiter {return}
set sourceFolder to (path to documents folder as text) & "AllProducts:"
set destinationFolder to (path to documents folder as text) & "SelectedProducts:"

--Step 2.  Process each record (data row) by first extracting the record data as text items.
repeat with thisRecord in csvRecords
    set recordItems to my getItems(thisRecord)

    -- Enter processing code here
    set filePath to sourceFolder & thisRecord
    log filePath

    tell application "Finder"
        if (exists file filePath) then
            duplicate file filePath to folder destinationFolder
        else
            log "File doesn't exist" & thisRecord
        end if
    end tell


end repeat

--Subroutine that returns the text items from each record.
on getItems(theRecord)
    copy the text item delimiters to origDelims
    set the text item delimiters to ","
    set recordItems to {}
    set recordItems to every text item of theRecord
    set the text item delimiters to origDelims
    return recordItems
end getItems
```

Comment: The `C` of CSV could be more than comma (tab, semicolon etc.). Before moving the files you need to separate the fields. Two other notes: The Finder accepts only HFS paths (colon separated) and the command to *copy* files is **duplicate** rather than copy.

Comment: I edited the code using some of your suggestions. Now it reads correctly the files but somehow only the first record matches correctly not the rest

Comment: You're using delimiter return, your line ending maybe something different depending on the format of the .csv. DOS uses \r\n vs. just \r or \n like UNIX or Mac files. My guess is that your .csv file is DOS formatted and therefor the second line of your data is left prefixed with \n and no such file exists with a volume prefixed with a \n

Comment: indeed that was the issue changed delimiter to {return, linefeed} and it worked! Thanks alot for your help!